# How to add current year's all dates to SQL server?

Tags: sql-server

Is it possible to add all the dates between 1st Jan-31-Dec in MS Sql server using query?

If someone has done it before please guide me to right track.

Thanks

Comment: "add all the dates"? What do you mean exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DECLARE @dt  Date
SET @dt = '2015-01-01'
WHILE @dt < '2016-01-01'
BEGIN
    SELECT @dt
    --INSERT .....
    SET @dt = DATEADD(DAY, 1, @dt)
END
```

Of course it depends on your table structure

Comment: Thanks mohan and simone your solution will do the trick. You both have provided correct solution for my needs.

Comment: You're welcome ... you could up vote the working solutions and/or select an answer

Comment: Inserting row by row in a table is not effective. Since it is once per year I doubt it will make much difference. But problems like this should only result in 1 insert.

Comment: Hi simone I have upvoted to both of you ..... Confused to mark answer as I can only mark one answer and you both have provided correct solution... So I'll wait for few days and who will get high upvotes will be marked as answer 

Hope you understand

Comment: I understand, i think it could be considered a fair behavior ... being honest the best solution is the last one :)

Answer (score 1):

using loop we can achieve this

```
Declare @date table(d datetime)
Declare @d datetime, @d1 datetime, @d2 datetime
Declare  @inc INT

set @d1='20150101'
set @d2='20151231'


Set @inc = DATEDIFF(D, @d1, @d2)

Set @d = @d1


While @d<=@d2
Begin
Insert into @date values (@d)
set @d=@d+1

End
Select d as DateCol from @date
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
DECLARE @year int = 2015

;WITH N(N)AS 
(SELECT 1 FROM(VALUES(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))M(N)),
tally(N)AS(SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY N.N)-1 FROM N,N a,N b,N c,N d,N e,N f)
SELECT top (datediff(d, cast(@year as char(4)), cast(@year + 1 as char(4)))) 
    CAST(DATEADD(d, N, cast(@year as char(4))) as date)
FROM tally
```

Result:

```
2015-01-01
2015-01-02
..
..
2015-12-31
```